# Filtering and searching with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm doing my first DRF project and wondered if it's possible to use the `DjangoFilterBackend` for filtering specific fields and use a search Filter at the same time. So a request would look something like:

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/test/?search=test&id=27&author=2672`

Is it possible to do this with `DjangoFilterBackend` or would I have to write my own filter logic?

If you need more information on the project itself or my code just let me know :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Example:

```
from rest_framework import filters
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ProductViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):       
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ["is_discontinued",]
    search_fields = ["name", "description",]
```

in **filterset_fields** enumerate the fields you want to filter by.
And in **search_fields** by which you want to search.

URL:

```
https://www.myurl.ltd/api/products?is_discontinued=False&search=laptop
```

More info:
[DjangoFilterBackend](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) and
[SearchFilter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Works as intended

Answer (score 0):

**Here I added a exaple code to use Django filter, It will be helpful to implement Django filter:**

```
# Use to filter specific fields
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
# import models
from app_crops.models import (Crop, CropVariety)


class CropNameFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    """
        Filter of crop name
    """
 
    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='contains')

    class Meta:
        model = Crop
        fields = ['name']


class CropListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    
    
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Crop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CropResponseSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = CropNameFilter  # Use the custom filter class

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user 
        req_serializer = CropLAVCustomReqSerializer(data=self.request.GET.dict())
        if req_serializer.is_valid():  
            if 'page_size' in self.request.GET:
                self.pagination_class = PaginationSetup.custom_standard_pagination(page_size=self.request.GET['page_size'])
            if 'crop_type_id' in self.request.GET:
                return Crop.objects.filter(crop_type=self.request.GET['crop_type_id'], country=self.request.GET['country_id'])

            return Crop.objects.filter(
                country=self.request.GET['country_id']
            ) 
        raise CustomAPIException(req_serializer.errors)
```